# Python - Why is my list turning into a tuple when passing it to a method with varargs (keywordonly)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variadic-functions

I pass a list to a method which accepts multiple params (*values). If I pass multiple values separated by "," its all fine, but if I pass a list *values turns into a tuple and doesnt iterate the values and the only element is the list I would like to iterate. Can somebody explains that? Is there some way to work around that, that both ways work?

My method:

```
    def accept(*values): 
        for value in values:
            #do something with value
```

Works:

```
foo.accept(value1, value2, value3)
```

Doesnt work:

```
values = [value1, value2, value3]
foo.accept(values)
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to unpack the list in the function call with the `*` operator:

```
foo.accept(*values)
```

Answer (score 5):

How the multiple parameters feature in python works is that you can pass in a variable number of arguments to the function, and it will automatically turn them into a list (so you don't have to manually) and then execute the code in the function. So when you do `foo.accept(value1, value2, value3)`, it creates a list `[value1, value2, value3]` and labels this list as the argument to your function, and then you code iterates through the list. However, when you do

```
values = [value1, value2, value3]
foo.accept(values)
```

the variable arguments (varargs) feature will wrap your values list into another list so now the argument to your function is `[[value1, value2, value3]]` and when your for loop does the iteration, it only goes through the one element in this bigger list (the one element being your values list).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid this additional wrapping of my list and always iterate the items (e.g value1, value2, value3) and wasnt able to find a solution until mgilson came up with it. I didnt know you can unwrap this list.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is explicitly for taking an arbitrary number of arguments a input

```
def accept1(*values): 
    #do something with values
```

For any given number of arguments it's exactly the same as writing, e.g.:

```
def accept2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    values = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
    #do something with values
```

To call a function with 3 arguments you can write for both as usual:

```
accept1(1,2,3)
accept2(1,2,3)
```

But if you have the arguements in a list or tuple you could do

```
args = (1,2,3)
accept1(args[0], args[1], args[3])
accept2(args[0], args[1], args[3])
```

This of course is inflexible and a lot to write so python has a shortcut that again works for an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
accept1(*args)
accept2(*args)
```

So in both cases that `*` denotes a generic way to handle multiple parameters by either

- packing individual arguments of a function into a list (in def), or
- unpacking a list into individual arguments of a function.

Answer (score 0):

From the Python 2.7.10 documents (slight edit):

> 4.7.3. Arbitrary Argument Lists
>
> Finally, the least frequently used option is to specify that a function can be called with an arbitrary number of arguments, i.e. using *args. These arguments will be wrapped up in a tuple.

Another point that might help in our understanding is that in Python the parenthesis are redundant in the following line of code:

`a = (1, 2, 3)`

It would have been enough to write:

`a = 1, 2, 3`

So onto answering the question. When you have foo.accept(1, 2, 3) the variable arguments get wrapped into a tuple. To verify this step through the code using your favorite debugger into accept() and find that there the arguments have indeed been wrapped in a tuple:

```
values = (1, 2, 3)
```

This is what is expected by definition, and the iteration goes over the three elements of the tuple 1, 2, and 3.

On the other hand when you call foo.accept([1, 2, 3]), again, by definition the argument gets wrapped in a tuple. To verify this step through the code into accept() and find:

```
values = ([1, 2, 3])
```

This might be unexpected, but it is the way *args are passed. Now the iteration goes over the one element in the tuple [1, 2, 3].

A workaround is usually specific with what is trying to be achieved. But perhaps something as simple as:

```
foo.accept(1, 2, 3)
```

or:

```
foo.accept(*[1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: precisely
take care of de-structuring an array definition into a series of array extension (see below), because forgetting a single comma may turn an assignement into a "create a tuple of that and a None, then perform the assignement"

example:
from ...
a = [ 1, 2, 3]
into ....
a = 1, # see the comma? it gives a "(1,)", a tuple of one element
a.extend(2)
a.extend(3)